# The notion of block in Python

Tags: python

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program) states:

> A Python program is constructed from code blocks. A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition.

This seems to imply, contrary to what I had thought, that an indented piece of code, such as the body of an if-statement or a for-loop is not a *block*.

Am I reading this correctly? What does it mean to be executed as a unit (e.g. why wouldn't a for-loop fit this definition)? What would you call an indented piece of code if not a block?

Comment: I think they are defining their own notion of a block, which is not exactly equivalent to the general idea of a "block" in programming. So no, indented pieces of code do not form a block necessarily in Python. A for loop does not get its own execution frame, so according to this definition, it isn't a block.  This would definitely get confusing if you mix the two notions

Comment: So yes, I think you are reading this correctly. I think "executed as a unit" means "executed using the same execution frame". For the record, I think this is a good question, not sure why it is garnering so many downvotes

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Loops etc. don't have their own frame and scope. 3. [Suite](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-suite).

Comment: Can you enlighten this noob: what is the significance of "block" and how it's defined in how we'd go about the business of coding in Python? (Sincerely, I'm interested - not trying to poke or troll)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Variables defined in the for-loop are local to the loop. So, why isn't for-loop an execution frame?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning **they absolutely are not local to the loop**. This is trivial to test; `for i in range(10): pass` then outside, `print(i)`

Comment: or if you aren't convinced, `for _ in range(1): x = 'hi'` then outside the loop, `print(x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh, got confused by PyLance saying that `i` might be unbound...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning right, it *might* be since the loop may never execute

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I use `i` right after the loop, how can it be unbound? If I get to that line, then the loop has executed...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning um, no. Try `for i in range(0): pass` then `print(i)` I guess I should say, the loop had zero iterations instead of "didn't execute".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Great point. Unlike C for-loop, we are looping over a collection, which might be empty. I learned something today.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga However, I really don't like variables in compound statements not being local to the statement... Why wouldn't Python allow me to have a small scope for variables?

Comment: I've honestly never missed it. But I can see how it could encourage bad practices. But you could always use a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This seems to imply, contrary to what I had thought, that an indented piece of code, such as the body of an if-statement or a for-loop is not a *block*.

Indeed, at least in the technical context of the Python language reference, what we would normally call an "indented block" is not a "block".

It's not unusual in technical specifications that words are given specific contextual meanings which are different to their usual meanings, and unfortunately sometimes this happens when the usual meaning is also a technical one.

> What would you call an indented piece of code if not a block?

The Python language reference calls it a [suite](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html). But I think most Python programmers would rather call it a block, unless they were proposing an edit to the language reference.

> What does it mean to be executed as a unit (e.g. why wouldn't a for-loop fit this definition)?

This means that a "block" (in the strict technical sense of the Python language reference) corresponds with a [code object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/code.html), is executed in a stack frame, and has its own lexical scope.

A `for` loop does not meet this definition because it does not have its own code object, stack frame or lexical scope; its bytecode is part of the containing block's code object, it is executed in the containing block's stack frame, and it has the containing block's lexical scope.

Practically, all this means is that variables declared inside a `for` loop (or any other suite) are still in scope after the suite has executed, until the end of the "block".

---

> I really don't like variables in compound statements not being local to the statement... Why wouldn't Python allow me to have a small scope for variables?

C-like languages have "block scope" (where the word "block" here means a sequence of statements delimited by a pair of braces), but they also allow you to declare variables without assigning to them yet, so you can declare them in the correct scope even if the assignment will occur in a different scope. For example, the following is totally fine in C, Java or similar languages:

```c
int x;
if(condition) {
    x = 5;
} else {
    x = 7;
}
```

But Python is a dynamic language in which you don't need to declare variables before you assign to them, so the equivalent Python code would be:

```py
if condition:
    x = 5
else:
    x = 7
```

If Python's "suites" had their own lexical scopes then this pattern wouldn't work; `x` would be local to the `if` and `else` scopes and would not be in scope afterwards. To get the same behaviour as the C code, you'd have to write a dummy `x = None` assignment before the `if` statement in order to declare `x` in the correct scope (and, perhaps, `nonlocal x` so that the assignments in the `if` and `else` suites would not instead declare new local variables in their own scopes). This would be silly and with very little upside, so it makes sense that Python is not designed that way.